# Динамическая передача вывода grep в файл

Tags: linux, bash, логирование, grep

Мне необходимо из syslog(/var/log/syslog) динамически обновлять, фильтровать и выводить строки с необходимым значением в файл.
Грубо говоря делаем
tail syslog -f | grep systemd в терминале получаем:

```
Sep 17 12:57:42 debian systemd[1]: *.service: Succeeded.
Sep 17 12:57:42 debian systemd[1]: Stopped * Web Service.
Sep 17 12:57:42 debian systemd[1]: Starting * Web Service...
Sep 17 12:57:42 debian systemd[1]: Started * Web Service.
Sep 17 12:58:02 debian systemd[1]: Stopping * Web Service...
Sep 17 12:58:02 debian systemd[1]: *.service: Main process exited
```

И обновляется это все автоматически.
Как вывести это в файл?

У меня только идея это: tail syslog -f | grep systemd >  echo >> /root/systemd.log
Но в файл ничего не передается от слова совсем (Или задержка передачи какая-то огромная.
Как можно динамически близко к реал-тайму передавать данные в файл?

Comment: `tail syslog -f | grep systemd >> /root/systemd.log` - в таком виде пробовали выполнять запись?

Comment: Если же это нужно регулярно, то правильнее научить логгер (syslog или что там у вас) сразу писать в дополнительный файл

Comment: @ipatev_nn да, в таком виде пробовал, тоже вывода никакого.

Comment: @AlexeyTen нет возможности настроить данное. Так что необходимо вот какими-то потусторонними силами вытаскивать вручную, в этом как-бы и проблемка...

Comment: Что значит «вывода никакого»? В файле пусто?

Comment: @AlexeyTen да, в файл ничего не приходит

Comment: Где вы это пишете?

Comment: @AlexeyTen открываю терминал ввожу tail syslog -f | grep systemd >> /root/systemd.log терминал выполняет операцию (как и должно быть)
открываю еще 1 терминал в котором делаю просто tail syslog -f | grep systemd имеем динамический вывод в консоль
Далее открываем еще один терминал вводим sudo systemctl restart %servicename%
Во втором терминале, где динамически выводится в консоль вывод есть, открываем файл, в файле пусто

Comment: `/root/systemd.log` - на каталог и файл есть права на запись?

Comment: [`--line-buffered`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7162898/4827341) (в современных версиях gnu/grep тоже уже имеется).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

программа *grep* (если *stdin* остаётся открытым, а *stdout* — **не** терминал) для повышения производительно буферизует выводимую информацию. пока не заполнился буфер вывода, она ничего не выводит.

чтобы программа не ожидала заполнения буфера, а отправляла информацию по-строчно, можно использовать опцию `--line-buffered`.

---

пример. вот так выводит (и остаётся работать):

```
$ echo x > файл
$ tail -f файл | grep x
x
```

а тут  (для простоты взята запись в «трубу» (pipe), а не файл) не выводит ничего потому, что у первого из процессов *grep* вывод осуществляется **не** в терминал:

```
$ tail -f файл | grep x | grep x
```

добавляем опцию `--line-buffered` — вывод идёт по-строчно:

```
$ tail -f файл | grep --line-buffered x | grep x
x
```

---

другой вариант: запускать процесс *grep*, «обёрнутый» вызовом *stdbuf* (с опцией `-o0`, означающей отключение буферизации):

```
$ tail -f файл | stdbuf -o0 grep x | grep x
x
```

Comment: Спасибо за --line-buffered
В дополнение могу сказать, что если указывать tail -n*** и -f, то в GREP обновления работать не будут вообще, он просто передаст последние *** строк и все, больше обновлять не будет. Баг или фича это, непонятно. Debian 10 
 grep версии 3.3-1

Comment: `man tee` И не надо ничего придумывать.