# Как в bash скрипте раскрасить вывод в консоль более чем одним цветом, с помощью tail -f и grep?

Tags: bash, grep

Есть скрипт который раскрашивает ошибки из "tail -f" в красный по дефолту:

```
tail -f $namelogC | grep --color -Ei "\[prog err\].*|error.*|$"
```

Можно ли на лету еще часть этого же текста покрасить в зелёный например, не используя других программ.

Нагуглил такой вариант:

```
 tail -f $namelogC | GREP_COLOR='01;36' egrep --color=always -i "\[prog err\].*|error.*|$"\
 | GREP_COLOR='01;31' egrep -i --color=always 'ping|$'
```

Но когда выполняю в консоль ничего не выводится.

Comment: Добавьте в первый греп опцию `--line-buffered`. Как вот тут https://askubuntu.com/a/685008/932746

Comment: Сработало, спасибо!

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Динамическая передача вывода grep в файл](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1329338/%d0%94%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b0-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0-grep-%d0%b2-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb)